# How to push image from private registry to hub.docker.com?

Tags: docker, docker-registry, dockerhub

I'm migrating a project from a private registry to [hub.docker.com](http://hub.docker.com/) but I don't have all tagged image on computer.

I have access to the registry machine via SSH.

#### Question

How can I push all my registry images to hub.docker.com?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the only way is to pull them all, then retag them and push to hub.docker.com

You can script it with something like:

```
for repository in $(curl -s http://localhost:5000/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[]'); do
  for image in $(curl -s http://localhost:5000/v2/${repository}/tags/list | jq -r '(.name + ":" + .tags[])')
    docker image pull localhost:5000/${image}
    docker image tag localhost:5000/${image} <YOUR_HUB_PREFIX>/${image}
    docker image push <YOUR_HUB_PREFIX>/${image}
    # if you need some cleanup
    docker image rm localhost:5000/${image} <YOUR_HUB_PREFIX>/${image}
  done
done
```

Comment: That was one of the idea, but unforntunately my current company bandwidth is terrible so it will takes weeks to do so

Comment: You can do this on the host where you have your registry to minimize the bandwidth on pull, but you'll still have to push every image...

Answer (score 0):

Access to your registry machine via SSH, use `docker login` to login inside your Docker Hub account, add a tag to your images which points to Docker Hub `docker tag my_own_registry.com/image:tag user/image:tag` a then push that new tag using `docker push user/image:tag`.

[@zigarn](https://stackoverflow.com/users/439790/zigarn) script automates this job.

Edit: You commented that your bandwith is bad, then you can access via ssh to your registry machine, save your image using `docker save`, then copy it to your machine and load it by `docker load` and finally push it to Docker Hub as explained above.